# change SRID of shapefile and QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, srid

It is possible to change the SRID from a shapefile to another SRID in QGIS ?
I have a shapefile in 2100 srid and i want to change it in 4326 SRID.

Comment: You need to refine your question : either you need to **project** from one to another (which will compute the coordinates differently), either you need to **redefine** the coordinate system (that will only change the metadata contained in the prj file)

Comment: Yes, the two operations are *very* different. Either the coordinates are correct in 2100 needing to be projected to 4326 or the coordinates are incorrect in 2100 and need to be redefined to 4326. Verify against a known to be accurate source (like open street map) - ensure you have project on the fly checked in QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rightclick, `Save As ...` to a new file and different CRS will do what you want.

You can not just change the SRID, but you have to recompute all coordinates as well. That is only done by `Save As ...`, and not with `Set CRS for Layer`